Verifying data but valid values depends on other columns
I have a Pandas dataframe built like this:



Fruit
Color
Eaten?
Date Eaten




Apple
Red
Yes
14-Mar-2024


Apple
Green
No
14-Mar-2024


Apple
Yellow
Yes



Banana
Red




Banana
Yellow
Yes
14-Mar-2024



I'm trying to create some rules for verifying my data, but what's valid depends on the value in other columns, e.g. "Red" is valid when the Fruit is "Apple", but not when the Fruit is "Banana"; Having a Date Eaten is valid when Eaten is "Yes", but not when Eaten is "No"
I'd like to be able to take a csv with previously manually verified data, make a set of rules from that, store those rules in a file for later use, and then use those rules to check new data. Ideally I'd just be able to get a Dataframe with all rows where there's invalid data, but I'm not too picky about that.
Looked into setting up rules manually, but there too many possible combinations, so that seemed impractical.
Googling sent me to decision trees, which seemed promising, but seemed more useful for predictions based on graphable data rather than verifying exact strings.

Inferring general rules from a valid file is a difficult, possibly impossible, problem.

Why would that be impossible?

How is it supposed to know which relationships are significant for validation and which are just incidental from a few examples.

For instance, in your example table, how would it know that Eaten relates to Date Eaten and not to Fruit?

At the very least you're talking about artificial intelligence to recognize ad hoc patterns.

what do you mean, all relationships would be significant for validation.

So Date Eaten must always be 14-Mar-2024 for Fruit==Apple?

Yes, exactly! (in reality I would probably just convert the Date Eaten column into True/False if there is a date)

Building masks is what you are looking for. Here an example how you could check the 'correct' color of a fruit.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fruit': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Banana'],
    'Color': ['Red', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Yellow']})

mask = df.Fruit == 'Banana'
df.loc[mask, 'check_fruit_color'] = df.Color[mask] == 'Yellow'

mask = df.Fruit == 'Apple'
df.loc[mask, 'check_fruit_color'] = df.Color[mask].isin(['Green', 'Red'])





Fruit
Color
check_fruit_color




0
Apple
Red
True


1
Apple
Green
True


2
Apple
Yellow
False


3
Banana
Red
False


4
Banana
Yellow
True



Answers to the secondary questions

It will also be possible to import conditions from a file. One approach might be to check whether a set of combinations exists in both tables or not. However, it will be very much tailored to the specific problem and there is no generic solution for it.

It is also possible to do this with an ML approach, where a decision tree should definitely be your first juice. However, it will require that you are familiar with basics such as masking anyway to verify that your model delivers.


